# Quick way to wipe xcode version control history to resolve issues?

Tags: xcode8

I've been working on a project for a few months using branches, and branches from branches to allow me to roll back to various points. I realise this may not be best practise!

I tried merging into master and got hundreds of errors so instead removed all branches except the current one. Again that might have been bad.

I'd now like to make the current branch the master but a number of files have version control symbols next to them and will not commit.

I tried Product->Clean but is there a way to effectively say to xcode 'make this the master and track all changes from now'. I don't even mind if I lose the change history.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this post](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28663538/detach-all-working-copies-and-reset-all-version-history-in-Xcode-6-3.html) I was able to work this one out.

1. Turn off source control: Xcode -> Preferences -> Source Control -
   Uncheck 'Enable source control'
2. Show hidden files in Terminal: "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean TRUE; killall Finder"
3. Remove .svn folders from your project
4. Hide hidden files again in Terminal: "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean FALSE; killall Finder"
5. Remove project from recent projects list: File -> Open Recent -> Clear Menu
6. Turn source control back on: Xcode -> Preferences -> Source Control -
   Check 'Enable source control'

This effectively restarts version control using the current files as master.